# Cumulative normalized histogram in Python

Tags: python, histogram

I have four arrays (A30, A300, B30, B300) and I want to create a cumulative, normalized histogram in Python so that the A300 curve ends at 1. I'm looking to normalize the four histograms so that the histogram of A300 will be visibly taller than the rest. However, I do NOT want the area under all four curves to add up to 1. Is there any simple way of doing this with numpy or calculating it?

Comment: Any attempts you have tried so far?

Comment: Please give sample arrays or something else, so that people can help clear your doubts. Are you trying to normalise everything by area (total) of A300?